# applying random forest in place of decision tree method in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am relatively new to random forest technique. I applied decision tree successfully to a data predicting 1/0 outcome. The predictors are mixture of continuous and categorical.

I was trying similar to tree method:

train_tree <- randomForest(Response_variable ~ predictor1 + predictor2+...predictor10 ,trainData,ntree=50)

But its throwing me error.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
2: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Hopefully these link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143450/r-randomforest-for-classification and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689760/r-is-there-a-way-to-find-inf-inf-values

Comment: but a decision tree works fine, why would there be any problem with data with randomForest? when it does only bootstrap trees.

Comment: Well the "in addition" warning is saying you shouldn't run a regression tree because the dependent variable has very few levels. So, random forest is assuming you want a regression tree not a decision tree.

Comment: you mean randomForest doesnt' work with binomial response?

Comment: It looks like random forest doesn't accept character values similar to rpart. i changed the variables to numeric.